# Why they use "would" in this case?

Tags: grammar

If it's to practice a specific writing style--business-related letters in this case--t***he easiest way would be to read various examples***. Afterward, or while reading, compose new business letters about any topic.

Comment: Is the whole body text a quote from somewhere?

Comment: It's the "would" that occurs in the apodosis of remote conditionals where it indicates modal remoteness. Contrasts with the "will" that occurs in open conditionals.

Comment: ie it's merely a more 'hedged' version of '– the easiest way will be to read various examples.' Here, 'hedged' covers distancing, as BillJ says, which in turn involves less abruptness, and something of a disclaimer if the suggested course of action doesn't seem to work. So subsets 'oiling discourse ... politeness' and 'back-covering-.

Comment: Using ***would*** instead of ***is*** or ***will be*** can reflect "deference" ***and / or*** "uncertainty". But sometimes it doesn't really carry either of those implications - it's just an "established" format that people are used to using.

Comment: "If you were to do it" is implied.

Answer (score 0):

Either 'is' or 'would be' are appropriate in this example. However, 'would be' will often be preferred in this type of sentence because it implies a possible course of action in the future, while using 'is' is more of a judgement that that way is in fact the easiest possible way.

However, especially in spoken conversation someone might choose 'is' without actually meaning the extra implication of it being the easiest possible way.

The difference could be used by a writer as a subtle way to contrast personalities, but it would be very subtle unless it was part of a larger pattern.